# Left [Outer] Join without Intersection to get count

Tags: t-sql

I have the following schema

[image]

I wanted to get all cars along with `number of models` for each car and `number of remaining colors` for each car.
I was able to get `number of models` but i am not able to get `number of remaining colors` for each car. I know i have to do Left [Outer] Join without Intersection. But its not working

I may also have model which does not have any colors. In such case there wont be any entry in `ModelColors` table

```
select 
    c.CarID,
    c.CarName,
    T1.[Num Of Models],
    T2.[Remaining Colors]
from Cars c
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT m.CarID, COUNT(1) AS 'Num Of Models' 
        FROM Models m
        GROUP BY m.CarID
    ) AS T1 ON T1.CarID = c.CarID
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT m1.CarID, COUNT(1) AS 'Remaining Colors' 
        FROM Colors col
        LEFT JOIN ModelColors mc on mc.ColorID = col.ColorID
        LEFT JOIN Models m1 on m1.ModelID = mc.ModelID
        WHERE mc.ColorID IS NULL
        GROUP BY m1.CarID
    ) AS T2 ON T2.CarID = c.CarID
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `from/join` clause in the second derived table (`T2`) is wrong.
You should use `Models` and `ModelColors` only:

```
SELECT m1.CarID, COUNT(1) AS 'Remaining Colors' 
FROM Models m
LEFT JOIN ModelColors mc
    ON m.ModelID = mc.ModelID
```

The entire query should look like this:

```
SELECT 
    c.CarID,
    c.CarName,
    T1.[Num Of Models],
    T2.[Remaining Colors]
FROM Cars c
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT m.CarID, COUNT(1) AS 'Num Of Models' 
        FROM Models m
        GROUP BY m.CarID
    ) AS T1 ON T1.CarID = c.CarID
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT m1.CarID, COUNT(1) AS 'Remaining Colors' 
        FROM Models m
        LEFT JOIN ModelColors mc
            ON m.ModelID = mc.ModelID
    ) AS T2 ON T2.CarID = c.CarID
```

Since you only want to count the colors, you don't need the Colors table at all for this query.